# Java - P2P Multicast Chat program - Error while implementing 1 - 1 chat between peers

Tags: java, sockets, p2p

I'm implementing a **P2P Multicast Chat program using Java Socket**. First, this is what i aim to do: in a network which has many clients, I want each client to be able to do a 1-1 chat with another clients (**many clients at a time, but 1-1 chat only**).
        So this is my current code:

- At first, after registering with the server, the client will start it own "server" used to handle 1-1 connections from other clients

  ```
  Thread starter = new Thread(new ClientListenerStart());
  starter.start();
  ```

  - Now this is the code for `ClientListenerStart` class:

    ```
    public class ClientListenerStart implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        currentConnectedClientsWriter = new ArrayList();
        currentChattingUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            // create a ServerSocket to listen to another clients' requests
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (true) {
                Socket _clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
                PrintWriter _clientWriter = new PrintWriter(_clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                currentConnectedClientsWriter.add(_clientWriter);
                Thread clientToClientHandler = new Thread(new ClientToClientHandler(_clientSocket, _clientWriter));
                clientToClientHandler.start();
            } // end while
        } // end try // end try
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR at server: ServerStart > run " + ex.toString());
        } // end catch
    } // end go()
    ```

    }
- next, when a client click in each other clients' name in a *jList*, **it creates a socket to that clicked client's server**. From that time they will communicate through that socket.

  ```
  // this method start the listening server in each client
      private void jListOnlineUsersMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                              
          JList list = (JList) evt.getSource();
          if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
              // if double-click
              jListOnlineUsersIndex = list.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
              String targetUsername = onlineUsernames.get(jListOnlineUsersIndex);
              String targetIP = onlineUserIPs.get(jListOnlineUsersIndex);
              int targetPort = onlineUserports.get(jListOnlineUsersIndex);
              try {
                  Socket clientSock = new Socket(targetIP, targetPort);
                  InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSock.getInputStream());
                  BufferedReader newClientReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                  PrintWriter newClientWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSock.getOutputStream());
                  // send chat request message
                  ClientChatRequestMsg clientChatRequestMsg = new ClientChatRequestMsg(username);
                  newClientWriter.println(clientChatRequestMsg.getXMLContent());
                  newClientWriter.flush(); // flushes the buffer
                  // assign targetUsername to currentRequestingUser - a global value
                  currentRequestingUser = targetUsername;
                  // create new thread for listening to the target client's responses
                  Thread ClientToClientHandler = new Thread(new ClientToClientHandler(clientSock, newClientWriter));
                  ClientToClientHandler.start();
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  System.out.println("ERROR at client: jListOnlineUsersMouseClicked " + ex.toString());
              }
          }
      }
  ```
- this is the code for `ClientToClientHandler` class:

  ```
  public class ClientToClientHandler implements Runnable {
          Socket clientSock;
          //declare buffer & writer used for communicate with CLIENT
          BufferedReader clientReader;
          PrintWriter clientWriter;
          public ClientToClientHandler(Socket clientSocket, PrintWriter _clientPrintWriter) {
              // new inputStreamReader and then add it to a BufferedReader
              clientWriter = _clientPrintWriter;
              try {
                  clientSock = clientSocket;
                  InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSock.getInputStream());
                  clientReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
              } // end try
              catch (Exception ex) {
                  System.out.println("ERROR at client: ClientToClientHandler constructor " + ex.toString());
              } // end catch
          } // end ClientToClientHandler()
          public void run() {
              String stream;
              try {
                  while ((stream = clientReader.readLine()) != null) {
                      System.out.println("CLIENT " + username +"'s stream from another client: " + stream);
                      switch (getMsgType(stream)) {
                          // this part handle the requestMsg from another client
                      }
                  }
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  System.out.println("ERROR at client: IncomingReaderClient > run " + ex.toString());
              }
          }
      }
  ```

  This is the my current error's description:
  After registered 3 clients: A, B and C with the server:
- client A connect and chat with client B normally. (1)
- Then client A connect and chat with client C normally. (2)

  - **The problem is that:** after (2), client A still can send msg to client B and client C. But when client B attemp a 1-1 chat with A, all of B's messages display in **A's chat window with C**. So I think client A is using only 1 channel to listening to the msg sent from other clients. But I don't know how to fix it yet...

I've been stucking in this problem for hours, really hope that you guys can help ! Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks so much in advanced !

Comment: i don't really hve straight answer, but 2 things, (1) isn't A already connected to B? so why B establish new connection to A, while B can just send msgs throught the established connection? (2) for sure, you need to have a different PORT for each client, so A->B[port 10], A->C[port 11], B->C[port 16]... etc

Comment: if you want to use 1 port, you have to implement your own Protocol, it could be simple or it could be complex, make some handshake which occurs 1st thing when connection is made, so the Peers exchange some Unique ID, this ID can be associated to the socket and chat window (using a Map or List) , from now on, all messages sent be Peers should contain that ID so receiver can know to which window this msg belongs...